# How to find search/find npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

What ways are there to find npm packages?

Below is community maintained listing compiled from the answers below.

#### npm Specific

- In console, `npm search <keyword>`
- https://www.npmjs.org/
- http://node-modules.com/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593402
- https://openbase.com/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/66827908/2752520

#### Generic

- https://github.com
- https://libraries.io

#### Dead

- http://browsenpm.org/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/24338500
- https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules
- http://toolbox.no.de/ aka http://nodetoolbox.com/
- http://packagefinder1-enome.dotcloud.com/
- http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571033
- https://nodejsmodules.org/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/17821476
- http://npmsearch.com/ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/34471018

Comment: I've gotta be honest, between the three of those, I don't know how you *couldn't* find a node package. haha are you searching for something in particular and not finding it?

Comment: @kristian this list is pretty good. But I am wondering if there is more(more is better...) :P.

Comment: @Kristian for example search for specific version of node only, or date, because I don't like old/unmaintained packages etc..

Comment: Perhaps keeping each item as a separate answer would be a good idea so people can vote them, leading to a crowd-sourced ranking.

Comment: For discussion on npm official issue tracker, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11519

Comment: nipster also seems dead

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's [nipster](http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/) too, based on npm + github rating.

Comment: actually the spelling is "nipstr", today I learned from google that a "nipster" is a nazi-hipster

Comment: Github repository URL has changed to [Nipster](https://github.com/eirikb/nipster) and the author has deployed the code to http://nipstr.com/ but it looks like it's outdated.

Answer (score 39):

`npm search` works pretty well:

`npm search connect`

`npm view` will show you the timestamp of each version and everthing else from `package.json` (including node version)

`npm view connect`

Answer (score 11):

[Libraries.io](https://libraries.io) is great for searching and filtering through NPM modules, you can also filter by license and keyword: https://libraries.io/search?platforms=NPM

Comment: It’s a great tool but have issue with not existing package versions and more [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/issues/2432)

Answer (score 6):

For me the best site for this purpose is Openbase:

https://openbase.com/

By VERY far. It's stats and features are, AFAIK, unmatched by any other site.

Answer (score 4):

https://npms.io is really nice, provides quality and maintenance stats too

Answer (score 3):

[npmsearch](https://npmjs.org/package/npmsearch) sorts the results by a combination of relevance and downloads. The command line version can be installed from npm:

```
[sudo] npm install -g npmsearch
```

disclamer: I am the author of npmsearch

---

[node-modules](http://node-modules.com/) allows you to personalize your results according to the modules that you have starred/followed on github

Comment: Demo link is dead. I've updated your answer to indicate this to make for easier browsing.

Answer (score 2):

For a fast method available in your console, type:

`npm search keyword`

*< Keyword >* searches **Title, Description, Author and Keywords** of all packages.

Comment: what's difference between `npm search` and `npm view`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one: https://npmaddict.com/

Not a search but daily list of New packages with at least 5 GitHub stars

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Enome/node-package-finder (Latest commit 26ff789  on 4 May 2012, should count as dead)

Answer (score 1):

https://nodejsmodules.org/ is one that lets you search, as well as browse by popularity

Comment: Nodetoolbox is dead now. Updated your answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [npmsearch.com](http://npmsearch.com/)

I'm not sure how it works internally but it usually gives the best results.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this question, I also created a tool to help people discover what npm packages other people are using:

http://www.npmdiscover.com

Answer (score 0):

It's sad but `npm search` won't work for me on node version 6+.

A quick workaround is by doing a curl from the command line:

```
curl --fail -O https://www.npmjs.com/package/q-promise 2>&1 | grep '404'
```

If this command returns nothing then the module exist if it does return a 404 the name is available for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

According to the NPM*S* (NPM *Search*) docs on how to [perform a search query](https://api-docs.npms.io/#api-Search), you can use the following operators in the npmjs.com search bar:

| Search Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `scope:types` | Show/filter results that belong to the @types scope |
| `author:sindresorhus` | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is the author |
| `maintainer:sindresorhus` | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is qualifier as a maintainer |
| `keywords:gulpplugin` | Show/filter results that have gulpplugin in the keywords (separate multiple keywords with commas, you may also exclude keywords e.g. `-framework`) |
| `not:deprecated` | Exclude deprecated packages from the results |
| `not:unstable` | Exclude packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| `not:insecure` | Exclude packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| `is:deprecated` | Show/filter is deprecated packages |
| `is:unstable` | Show/filter packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| `is:insecure` | Show/filter packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| `boost-exact:false` | Do not boost exact matches, defaults to true |
| `score-effect:14` | Set the effect that package scores have for the final search score, defaults to 15.3 |
| `quality-weight:1` | Set the weight that quality has for the each package score, defaults to 1.95 |
| `popularity-weight:1` | Set the weight that popularity has for the each package score, defaults to 3.3 |
| `maintenance-weight:1` | Set the weight that the quality has for the each package score, defaults to 2.05 |

#### Further Reading

- [Searching for and choosing packages to download](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download):
- [Find NPM packages by keywords and authors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52853838/1366033)
- [npms](https://github.com/npms-io) / [npms analyzer](https://github.com/npms-io/npms-analyzer)

Answer (score 0):

NPM can feel overwhelming because it is the *largest* package registry! Sometimes, we need less or a more curated suggestions when looking...

This is why I built https://pkg.land

It helps you find similar packages on npm, e.g https://pkg.land/moment will suggest you `dayjs`, `date-fns` etc.

It's still in beta but I do intend to maintain and improve it over time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).