# How can I exclude search terms on npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

I would like to search for, e.g. 'carousel' and exclude results with 'react' in them. I have tried:

```
carousel -react
```

and

```
carousel NOT react
```

But this still turns up results with 'react' in them. How can I exclude search terms on npm?

Comment: Through the website's search or `npm search`?

Comment: @Kenan preferable the website (it has slightly better looking results) but the shell would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I exclude search terms on npm?

If you are asking about NPM search in the shell I think the only way to exclude words is by using a **search regex** Here is an excerpt from the NPM Search documentation:

> If a term starts with /, then it's interpreted as a regular expression. A trailing / will be ignored in this case. (Note that many regular expression characters must be escaped or quoted in most shells.)

A very simple example of regex search is:

```
npm search /carousel/
```

Implementing the actual regex to exclude **react** is outside the scope of this question and it would involve creating a **negative lookahead/lookbehind** regex expression.

Comment: Downvote. The OP *explicitly* asked about how to **exclude search terms**. Saying this is out-of-scope of the question is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to do it specificly using npm, but you can also pipe it with grep:

`npm search carousel | grep -v -i react`

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on grep and used google:

`site:www.npmjs.com react camera -native`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`keywords:carousel,-react`

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Acarousel%2C-react

The downside is that it looks for the keywords aka. tags, so it requires that the authors have added carousel as a tag.

You can potentially expand your search a bit to all packages with "carousel" anywhere in their text, but which has not got a react keyword/tag:

`carousel keywords:-react`

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=carousel%20keywords%3A-react

For more search commands, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70463885/380607