# Get list of all packages on npm

Tags: npm

Is there an NPM equivalent to RubyGems:

```
gem list --remote --source=http://gems.github.com/
```

I am trying to get a list of just the package names available on npm

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10568512/827263

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3867

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but its fairly easy to replicate the NPM registry with couchDB, and then querying it for the information needed: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry

As of writing this, the entire clone is ~1.5GB of space, which includes lots of metadata.