# Is there a way to search/query NPM based on any of the attributes?

Tags: npm, dependencies

For e.g.: I would like to find out which npm published packages use the package {xyz}, in which case I would like to search by the dependencies.

Comment: Ok, so I have found the answer, but why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

https://npmsearch.com/ gives the ability to search using attributes, for instance: ?q=dependencies:amqplib. Found this while browsing this: [How to find search/find npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages/34471018#34471018).