# Npm - find out from command line whether the name was taken

Tags: npm

Is there a way to find out from command line whether a package name was taken?

I am looking for something similar to `bower info $name`. I don't want to use `npm install $name` to test it, so please don't send answers like that!

**Was marked as duplicate of**
[How to find search/find npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages)

My question is about finding out **whether a package name was taken** with the usage of a **command line tool**, not about getting a package name list based on a keyword using a tool with web interface. So these questions are far from being the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find search/find npm packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages)

Comment: @jurgemaister Thanks!

Comment: @jurgemaister Btw. that is not the exact same question, since I am looking for command line tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for npm that allows this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/namecheck

install it and then you can use the command

> namecheck name1 name2

And it'll check several names at once