# Create an expo project with a specific version

Tags: react-native, expo

How do you specify the expo version when creating a project? Such as in React Native you can just add the version in the command like this `react-native init projectName --version@0.60.0`

What about in `expo init projectName` ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no way to specify react native version in expo cli. But you can specify SDK version in expo cli. Each SDK corresponds to particular react native version you can find the react native version for the expo sdk here(https://github.com/expo/react-native/releases)

For example, if you want to work with react native 0.61.4, you can use expo sdk-37.0.1

```
expo init --template expo-template-blank@sdk-37.0.1
```

EDIT as of now, it depends on how you start your package manager.

```
npm create-expo-app [name] --template blank@45
yarn create-expo-app [name] --template blank@45
pnpm create-expo-app [name] --template blank@45
npx create-expo-app [name] --template blank@45
```

Unfortunately there's no nice way of doing an [npm search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages) but the pattern for the template is anything that starts with `expo-template` is a potential candidate.  The author you'd be looking for is `brentvayne` from Expo team.
Reference:

1. https://github.com/expo/react-native/releases
2. https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/?redirected
3. https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/142

Comment: And I guess if someone needs ejected version with ios and android folders then need to eject also.

Comment: Expo and React-Native major versions have a 1:1 mapping, so there is a way to specify the React-Native major version - by specifying the equivalent Expo major version.

Comment: You might want to replace `[npm|yarn|pnpm] create-expo-app` with `[npm|yarn|pnpm] create expo-app` (I tried `yarn create-expo-app` but it doesn't work, as of 2023)

Answer (score 3):

Mapping between React Native CLI versions and Expo is here:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/

[image]

In my case, available template names were: "blank, tabs, bare-minimum"

So when you would run

```
npx create-expo-app -t tabs@45
```

It will ask you for the app name, and when finished, you would have the app boilerplate installed using Typescript, and React Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

To add info to the accepted answer, and tags were changed on expo-template-blank (I have `No matching version found for expo-template-blank@sdk-37.0.1.`)

What I found to be working :

- `expo init --template expo-template-blank@37.0.1`
- `expo init --template expo-template-blank@sdk-37` for the latest sdk-37

To have an idea of current tags/branches and react-native dependency, I found this to be used internally by `expo-cli`:

`npx pacote packument expo-template-blank |jq .`

Note that for sdk <= 42, they would use their own repo and tag for react-native, making a pain to find a particular legacy version. You need to check manually in their repo for the actual react-native base version at `https://github.com/expo/react-native`

I extracted it for you :

```
git clone https://github.com/expo/react-native
cd react-native
for ((i=10; i<50; ++i)); do RN_VERSION=$(git cat-file  blob origin/sdk-$i:package.json|sed '/"version"/!d; s/.*: "\(.*\)",/\1/'); echo "sdk-$i => $RN_VERSION"; done
```

```
expo sdk version => react-native branch version
sdk-10 => 0.33.0
sdk-11 => 0.36.0
sdk-12 => 0.37.0
sdk-13 => 0.40.0
sdk-14 => 0.41.2
sdk-15 => 0.42.0
sdk-16 => 0.43.2
sdk-17 => 0.44.0
sdk-18 => 0.45.1
sdk-19 => 0.46.1
sdk-20 => 0.47.1
sdk-21 => 0.48.4
sdk-22 => 0.49.3
sdk-23 => 0.50.4
sdk-24 => 0.51.0
sdk-25 => 0.52.0
sdk-26 => 0.54.2
sdk-27 => 0.55.2
sdk-28 => 0.55.4
sdk-29 => 0.55.4
sdk-30 => 0.55.4
sdk-31 => 0.57.1
sdk-32 => 0.57.1
sdk-33 => 0.59.8
sdk-34 => 0.59.8
sdk-35 => 0.59.8
sdk-36 => 0.61.4
sdk-37 => 0.61.4
sdk-38 => 0.62.2
sdk-39 => 0.63.2
sdk-40 => 0.63.2
sdk-41 => 0.63.2
sdk-42 => 0.63.2
sdk-43 => 0.64.3
sdk-44 => 0.64.3
sdk-45 => 0.68.1
sdk-46 => 0.69.1
sdk-47 => 0.70.3
sdk-48 => 0.71.13
sdk-49 => 1000.0.0
```