# How can I create new react native expo project with older expo SDK version?

Tags: react-native, expo, sdk

New versions of React Native has some issues with debugger tools. So I want to create react native expo project with old react native version.

I have to use old version of expo SDK(like version 46.0.0) with
`npx create-expo-app StickerSmash`
command.

But documentation of create-expo-app is poor.
Is there a way to specify expo app SDK version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63464020

Comment: Yes. Actually I read that answer a few hours ago . But "npx create-expo-app -t tabs@45" confused me. But now I got it. Thank you.